# java.lang.VerifyError creating a gradle task with kotlin

Tags: java, gradle, kotlin

I try to write a gradle task with kotlin, this is my code.:

***GreetingTask.kt***

```
class GreetingTask : DefaultTask() {
    @TaskAction
    fun greet() {
        println("greet!")
    }
}
```

***build.gradle***

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:0.12.613"
    }
}

apply plugin: "kotlin"

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:0.12.613"
    compile gradleApi()
}
```

***GreetingTaskTest***

```
class GreetingTaskTest {

    @Test
    public fun canAddTaskToProject() {
        val project = ProjectBuilder.builder().build()
        val task = project.task(hashMapOf("type" to javaClass<GreetingTask>()), "greeting")
        assertTrue(task is GreetingTask)
    }
}
```

When running the test now it results in a:

```
java.lang.VerifyError at GreetingTaskTest.kt:20
// reason -> Cannot inherit from final class
```

Which is this line:

```
val task = project.task(hashMapOf("type" to javaClass<GreetingTask>()), "greeting")
```

What i would like to know is:

**Where does this issue come from and how do i fix it?**

Comment: I'd also like to add that a similar error happens with Gradle 2.14 when actually trying to *run* the task, through Gradle proper -- `Could not generate a proxy class for class X`. The fix is the same -- add `open` to the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Classes in Kotlin are final by default, compared to open in java.

Declare the class `GreetingTask` as "open" and this error message is gone.

```
open class GreetingTask : DefaultTask() { 
    ...
}
```

Comment: As simple as that. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: Would be good to point out which class to change, and just quickly show the syntax for using `open`.  In this case the `GreetingTask` must be made open, which would look like `open class GreetingTask : DefaultTask() { ... }`.  Read more at https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html#inheritance